# warning CS1570: XML comment on 'myclass' has badly formed XML -- 'A name was started with an invalid character.'

Tags: c#, doxygen, xml-comments

I have some C# codes using doxygen comments for some equations. VS2013 should me a warning message

```
warning CS1570: XML comment on 'myclass' has badly formed XML -- 
'A name was started with an invalid character.'
```

My comments are as follows and "<" caused this warning messages.

```
/// \f[
/// T_{max}<30
/// \f]
```

I really have to get rid of this warning messages. The best option is not to change the compile options to ignore this warning.

How should I fix it? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to escape the `<` - in XML it's `&lt;`.

So this would be valid:

```
/// \f[
/// T_{max}&lt;30
/// \f]
```

Now I don't know how doxygen handles comments in C# - if it really wants the original form, because it's not handling the comments as XML, then you should turn off XML commenting in the C# project settings. (Basically you either need to provide valid XML, or you need to stop anything from expecting it to be valid XML.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. It is working for C# and doxygen.